# When a user registers... Leave his data empty or fill it with demo values or ...?

Tags: navigation, registration, wizard, tutorial

So, i'm creating a web application for member management.

So a user registers... And then they go to the dashboard, to see everything empty.

What would be the best experience to let the user flow through your web application and start using it?

I'd think demo values aren't good, but should i integrate an extended tutorial when they first launch the page?

Eg. Some kind of process to iterate over all pages and let them first create a member and/ or an event?

What did you do or what do you think is best ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tutorial which users can leave at any time and come back to is your best option. Demo values will only confuse users if the values aren't accurate. But, in a tutorial-wizard like manor you should show all the options, with demo values and a demo user. This way you introduce the features of the site, and your user will quickly get up to speed of what they can do. Most important though is the ability to Close the tutorial, since some user may already have a task they need to solve Before they can be relaxed an Watch your tutorial. If you throw in context help as well, your users will love you!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Benny’s suggestion about a tutorial that can be accessed at any time. 
Consider also an interface like the StackExchange login window,
where dummy values/hints/prompts (such as “name@example.com” and “Password”)
are displayed in gray letters that disappear as soon as the user clicks there
(or as soon as he starts typing).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language you're coding in or what browsers you want to support, but going on the constructive dummy-text idea brought up by Scott, HTML5 placeholders might be your friend in this situation ([but not for replacing labels](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/28511/does-the-content-of-the-html5-placeholder-attribute-affect-usability)).