# Placeholder text example

Tags: usability, forms, input-fields, placeholder

I am looking for some feedback on placeholder text. We have several inputs that are currently blank (we're creating a form builder application). There are a few fields, specifically: No. (number), Label, and Description. I am wondering if we did not change the input labels and added placeholder text such as "e.g. What is your favorite food?" or other examples, would that be beneficial?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/28511/does-the-content-of-the-html5-placeholder-attribute-affect-usability?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

We use place holders extensively however we do not remove the labels.

The reasons is one screen readers needs the labels if you remove them them by replacing it with placeholders then it's not ideal for screen readers.

Also for general UX as soon as you type the placeholder disappears now imagine you have a large form like you mentioned and the user has to glance over it to make a change before submitting for example then be will be lost since the labels would have been a indicator of sorts.

To give you an examples how we use place holders:

I am going to type it Label followed by placeholder:

Name: 
Enter name here

Number:
+24 (079)  7723 809

Email:
Enter e-mail here

Etc etc